# Is it the same efficiency when I am using LIMIT clause in millions records and thousands records in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, limit

E.g:

I am going to using `JQuery ui autocomplet plugin`.The `suggestions  data` should be extracted from `MySQL databse`,and my sql query is:

```
SELECT `keywords`,`record_count`  FROM `suggestion_words`WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%'.$suggestions .'%' ORDER BY `search_count` LIMIT 0,10
```

As every one said,the `LIKE` is more slower.So,I just wonder,if I only return 10 records at every query,should it be the same efficiency in millions records and thousands records!?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MySql will still need to scan the entire table, so the more rows it needs to scan, the more time it will take.

Becouse MySql will only stop the **sorting** as soon as it finds 10 rows, if you only need 10 random records, you should think about doing the sorting in a outer subquery, so MySql can stop looking once 10 rows are found.

Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: What the "row_count" stand for in the limit-optimization documents?

Comment: the amount of rows to be returned, in your case `10`.